# Nested ScrollViewer ScrollChanged in ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer, controltemplate

I have a `ScrollViewer` bound with a `ControlTemplate` (which works fine), a `Grid` inside (which overrides the default `ScrollViewer` and sets the `ScrollBar`s "above" the content and finally I have some `EventTrigger`s which set the Opacity of the `ScrollBar` s to 1 or 0 in a `Storyboard`. They also work well.

What I am missing is one of this triggers that sets the `Opacity` to 1 in case the scrolling takes place. It can be scrolled by mouse, mousewheel, stylus or touch, so it would be best to take the `ScrollChanged` of the `ScrollViewer` or the `Scroll` of the `ScrollBar`s themselves. But I cannot make it work. Oh and btw. I cannot change the way it is build. So I have to make it by pure XAML inside the `ControlTemplate` (I know myself how to make it with code behind, but that is not possible here).

The style looks this way:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:ViewerControl}">
    // ... some properties of no interest here
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ViewerControl}">
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Name="PART_ScrollViewer">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:02" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:02" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseEnter">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.MouseLeave">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:02" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:02" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Grid.Triggers>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                               Opacity="0"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               IsTabStop="False"
                                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                                               Opacity="0"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               IsTabStop="False"
                                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Name="PART_ItemsHost" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I tried it with something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ScrollViewer.Triggers>
```

But if I put this directly inside the `ScrollViewer` it cannot find the `ScrollBar`s and if I put it inside the `Grid` it is completly ignored (the `Grid` itself has no control over the `ScrollViewer` and seems not to bubble this up to it.

I found an answer where someone used the VisualStateManager, but this only seems to work in Silverlight, not in C#. It looked like this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Has someone an idea how to make this work?

Comment: You have no access to code, just xaml? I mean not code of control, but can you, for example, create some custom behavior or attached property?

Comment: I can change the XAML and could even change more. But this Template is used in several different locations in several projects and I would need to make it that way, that I only have one location to change the code and it would be best not to change the code-behind at those locations. So if you want to ask if I could add a class or something the answer is yes. But I cannot do the code-behind edits at every project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coworker of mine found the answer:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" From="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:02" Duration="00:00:01.5" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_VerticalScrollBar"/>
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:02" Duration="00:00:01.5" From="1" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

So if you put the `EventTrigger` inside the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, it works like a charm... really cool. You only have to put these `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` inside the `ScrollBar`s or else they are also triggered if the cursor enters the content of the `ScrollViewer`, not only on entering the `ScrollBar`s.